# JavaScript самая длинная комбинация из k строк идущих подряд.

Tags: javascript, java, массивы, строки

Всем доброго времени суток, есть массив состоящий из строк к примеру

```
arr = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]
```

нужно создать функцию которая на основе данного ей массива выводила бы строку с самой длинной комбинацией строк идущих подряд, но кол-во строк ограничено в параметре функции. Пример :

```
LongestConc(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"], 2) == "abigailtheta"
```

Тут как видно ограничение по строкам 2 , то есть если посчитать все длинны строк в массиве выходит [4,7,5,4,4,3]  ну и самая длинная комбинация из 2 выходит из чисел 7+5 = 12 то есть - abigailtheta. Вот еще пример:

```
LongestConc(["it","wkppv","ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz"], 3) == "ixoyx3452zzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

Так вот , я не могу придумать как это осуществить. Главная проблема что комбинация должна идти подряд, иначе , я бы уже сделал(просто отсортировав массив по длине строк и в зависимости от заданного числа, просуммировал бы строки в цикле).

Comment: ну в начале отсортируй, выбери нужное количество, а дальше делай два цикла: пробегай по изначальному массиву и внутри по выбранным словам, при совпадении - заноси в строку.... это самый черновой, но рабочий вариант

Comment: А разве во втором примене результат не "wkppvixoyxzzzzzzzzzzzz"?

Comment: @Cheg как раз нет , ибо строки должны идти подряд, в этом вся загвоздка.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можете подробнее ? я не понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так, навскидку.

```js
let arr = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"];

function longestString(arr, k) {
  if (k > arr.length) {
    console.error('array is too short');
    return '';
  }
  let longest = '';
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - k; i++) {
    let current = arr.slice(i, i + k).join('');
    if (current.length > longest.length) {
      longest = current;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

console.log(longestString(arr, 2));
console.log(longestString(["it","wkppv","ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz"], 3));
```

Comment: Очень, очень красиво считаете сдвиг. Вау!

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ, а теперь можно поподробнее , хочется разобраться что к чему(плюс выходит так мало кода). 
В цикле мы просматриваем элементы от первого к последнему вычитая k,в current записываем комбинацию из k строк и просто сравниваем на каждой итерации длины?

Comment: даа код шикарен

Comment: @Ага позволю себе рассказать за автора. Первое условие - проверка что такой код возможен. Цикл for - строка с arr.slice - обрезает массив до нужного к-ва элементов, собирает в строку. Проверяет длину этой строки, если она больше того, что было до сохраняет ее. Возвращает)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko ну я так в принципе и понял, это гениально! 
Долбался с этой задачей целый день и никак не мог придумать, все время были ошибки в разных местах при проверке и код был огого. А тут - эффективный минимализм.

Comment: там прикаждой интерации записивается строка с елемента под номером "i" и до елемета под номером "i + k" в переменную "current". Потом проверятся, если "longest" меньше "current" - задаем новый "longer", после цикла просто возвращаем "longer"

Answer (score 1):

Вроде проще всего, что было до. Хотя бы внешне

```js
const arr = ["it", "wkppv", "ixoyx", "3452", "zzzzzzzzzzzz"];

function count(a, l) {
  var str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var s = '';
    for (let j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      if (typeof a[i + j] !== "undefined") {
        s += a[j + i];
      }
    }
    if (s.length > str.length) {
      str = s;
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

Пояснение: в конце будут лишние строки из двух, одного менее элементов массива. Так как длина больше 0 всегда они не влияют на р-т

Comment: Все работает, спасибо, но по простоте все же код @Yaant мне кажется проще, без обид) имхо.
тут и foreach, и халва с циклами и тд)

Comment: @Ага самое забавное, что принцип работы абсолютно одинаков. Это Вам для понимания).

Comment: @Ага чуть упростил

Comment: @ Vyacheslav Potseluyko Да так уже проще, все понятно) Но как же мне понравился ход со сдвигом arr.slice(i, i + k).join(''); у Yaant'a.

Answer (score 0):

Если будет не понятно что происходит - объясню в комнетариях)

```js
'use scrict';
var arr = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"];

function LongestConc(arr, number){
    //Сначало узнаем самую длинную строку из всех возможных
    var theMostLonger = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length - number;i++){
        //Каждый раз очищаем предыдущий запроси устанавливаем новых последующих елементов в массиве
        var length = 0,
            startPosition = i;
        //Здесь мы добавляем длинну строку от начального елемента до конца значения number
        for(var j=0;j<number;j++){
              length += arr[startPosition++].length;
        };
        //Если больше - устанавливаем новую саму длинную длинну
        if(length > theMostLonger) theMostLonger = length;
    };
    //Дальше запустим цикл который уже опеределит эти самые строки и слепит их воедино вернув нам значние
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length - number;i++){
        var length = 0,
            startPosition = i;
        for(var j=0;j<number;j++){
            length += arr[startPosition++].length;
        };
        if(length == theMostLonger){
            var returnString = '';
            for(var j=0;j<number;j++){
                returnString += arr[i++];
            }
            return returnString;
        }
    }
};

console.log(LongestConc(arr, 3));
console.log(LongestConc(arr, 2));
console.log(LongestConc(arr, 4));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , но при LongestConc(["ejjjjmmtthh", "zxxuueeg", "aanlljrrrxx", "dqqqaaabbb", "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehh"], 1) == "oocccffuucccjjjkkkjyyyeehh" выдает ошибку.
И тут :
 LongestConc(["itvayloxrp","wkppqsztdkmvcuwvereiupccauycnjutlv","vweqilsfytihvrzlaodfixoyxvyuyvgpck"], 2) =="wkppqsztdkmvcuwvereiupccauycnjutlvvweqilsfytihvrzlaodfixoyxvyuyvgpck"

Comment: да... поспешил с ответом)